# Is it possible to pause an iframe? (All scripts/css-animations stop)

Tags: animation, iframe

Take a look at the pens on codepen: http://codepen.io/

After a few seconds they all just stop. If you inspect the elements you'll see that they are in fact real iframes, but somehow they manage to "pause" them.

How is this made?

Answer (score 2):

I understand this is a very old post but for those who are still curious in 2018:

You need to

- Disable animations
- Disable audio/video elements
- Wrap this up and set a timeout
- Inject it into every iFrame

Don't worry, it is pretty easy and straightforward.

### Disable all CSS animations

The following will find and iterate through all the nodes rendered in the DOM. For each HTMLElement it will set the CSS properties to 'paused'.

```
function disablewebkitAnimations() {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('*')
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        style = nodes[i].style
        style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'paused'
        document.body.className = 'paused'
    }
}
```

### Disable audio/video

The following function will select all the elements of type *type*, iterate through them and simply call the *pause()* method.

```
function pauseElementTypes(type) {
    let nodes = document.querySelectorAll(type)
    for (var i = 0, els = document.getElementsByTagName(type); i < els.length; i++) {
        els[i].pause();
    }
}
```

Note: This will *not* stop Audio and Video elements not rendered in the DOM. This means if you create a new HTMLAudioElement then play it but don't append it to your document, it will keep playing. This is why some pens on CodePen in results still manage to make sound sometimes.

### Wrapping it up

A simple function that does everything we just described.

```
function iFrameDisable() {
    disablewebkitAnimations()
    pauseElementTypes("audio")
    pauseElementTypes("video")
}

setTimeout(iFrameDisable, 4000) // execute after 4 seconds
```

### Inject

Basically, on CodePen they inject the the following code in every iFrame of their search results. (the function names may differ but it is conceptually the same)

```
<script>
function disablewebkitAnimations() {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('*')
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        style = nodes[i].style
        style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'paused'
        document.body.className = 'paused'
    }
}

function pauseElementTypes(type) {
    let nodes = document.querySelectorAll(type)
    for (var i = 0, els = document.getElementsByTagName(type); i < els.length; i++) {
        els[i].pause();
    }
}

function iFrameDisable() {
    disablewebkitAnimations()
    pauseElementTypes("audio")
    pauseElementTypes("video")
}

setTimeout(iFrameDisable, 4000)
</script>
```

Read more about [disabling iFrames](https://dev.to/jochemstoel/how-to-disable-iframes-after-a-few-seconds-like-they-do-on-codepen-49b1) on dev.

Comment: This does not address scripts - all `requestAnimationFrame`, `setTimeout`, and `setInterval` need probed from the `window` and cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

It's done by the loaded content, see the source of http://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/full/pfxat (the iFrame path of the first one).

Comment: I don't really see your point. The link you posted doesn't stop animating, it just goes on forever. That's how i imagine it *should* work on the frontpage (or anywhere it's listed) as well. Instead, it stops animating after a few seconds. That's what i don't understand how it's done.

Comment: Have a look at the homepage, go to the iFrame and check the 3rd `script` tag. There is the function which does the work (it cancels all CSS animations)

Comment: I'm not seeing it, can you link it (or tell me what line)?